# mysqli_fetch_assoc while loop not working

Tags: php, mysql

*** if(!empty) retrieves first entry in array and shouldn't be used ***

This script searches a database for a url that matches the one submitted by a user in a form. Currently the $query printed by the echo statement works fine in mysql and returns one entry. This script executes and prints the table header, but doesn't enter the while($row =.. ) loop.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be really appreciated. I've used this method before with no trouble so I'm sort of stumped right now.

```
//1. Query DB for results

   $query = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE projectsurl='".$url."';";
    echo "<br>".$query;
    $projects = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

// 2. Print Project Results 

if(!empty(mysqli_fetch_assoc($projects))){
    //Print Project Results 
    echo "Is this your project?<br>";
    echo "<table style=width:'100%'>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($projects)){

    echo $tabler . $thh .  "Title: <br>" .$row['title'] . $thsp . "No. Rewards: <br>" . $row['rewards'] . $thf . $xtabler;
    echo $tabler . $thh . "ID: " .$row['id'] . $thf . $xtabler;
    // Echo two rows for the URL Strings because they are longer.
    echo $tabler . $thh . "<a href='" . $row['projectsurl'] . "'>Projects</a>" . $thsp . "<a href='" . $row['rewardsurl'] .  "'> Rewards " . $thf . $xtabler;
    echo "<form id='confirmation' action='../index.php' method='POST'>
            <input type='hidden' value='2' name = 'stage'>
            <input type='hidden' value='".$row['id']."' name='id'>
            <input type='hidden' value='".$row['title']."' name='title'>
            <input type='submit' value='Confirm'></form>";
    }

    echo "</table>";


    }else{
            //trigger ruby script to search for lost file
            echo "Project Not Found. <br>";




    }
```

Oh and the random table stuff is defined elsewhere as

```
$tabler = "<tr>";
$xtabler = "</tr>";

$thh = "<th><b>";
$thsp = "</th><th>";
$thf = "</b></th>";

$csp = "</td><td>";
$ch = "<td>";
$cf = "</td>";
```

Comment: You're already fetching one row in your `if(!empty(` statement and if you only have one row, then the while loop will never enter.

Comment: Use https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php instead

Comment: HA! Guess that's what happens when I try to be smart. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only one row, then `if(!empty(mysqli_fetch_assoc($projects))){` will fetch it and your `while` loop will not be entered. Instead, to check if a row exists, use `mysqli_num_rows($projects)`.

Also, **Reminder,** escape your user submitted data before using it in your MySQL query if you haven't already. This can be done by: `$query = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE projectsurl='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $url)."';";`

**EDIT:** Alternatively, prepare your MySQL statements before executing them. This is the preferred method, although both protect you from injections.

Comment: Escaping is an old technique and shouldn't be used anymore. Instead Prepared Statements should be used.